# Angularjs filter multiple checkbox on map

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-filter

I want to filter according to the materials in the room in the project. For example: if checked TV checkbox show the rooms on the TV. if checked tv and wifi checkbox just list rooms that are both TV and WiFi. My example shows the TV ones but when I press the wifi button the rooms with TV are still listed even though it is not WiFi.

This is: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toplumdusmani/zcgs7yf6/18)

```js
 angular.module('hotelApp', [])
    .controller('ContentControler', function ($scope, $timeout) {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
    $scope.location_name = "";
    $scope.names = [{
        prop_Name: 'Location 1',
        lat: 43.7000,
        long: -79.4000,
        amenities: '3'
    }, {
        prop_Name: 'Location 2',
        lat: 40.6700,
        long: -73.9400,
        amenities: '2'
    }, {
        prop_Name: 'Location 3',
        lat: 41.8819,
        long: -87.6278,
        amenities: '4'
    }, {
        prop_Name: 'Location 4',
        lat: 34.0500,
        long: -118.2500,
        amenities: '2'
    }, {
        prop_Name: 'Location 5',
        lat: 36.0800,
        long: -115.1522,
        amenities: '2, 3'
    }];
    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    $scope.markers = [];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var createMarker = function (info) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
            title: info.prop_Name
        });
        marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent"><ul>' + '<li>' + info.prop_Desc + '</li>' + '<li>' + info.prop_Addr + '</li>' + '<li>' + info.prop_Price + '</li>' + '<li>' + info.prop_Dist + '</li>' + '</ul></div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });

        $scope.markers.push(marker);

    }

    for (i = 0; i < $scope.names.length; i++) {
        createMarker($scope.names[i]);
    }

    $scope.openInfoWindow = function (e, selectedMarker) {
        e.preventDefault();
        google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
    }

//PROBLEM FILTER HERE   
$scope.am_en = function()
{
  x = $(".hosting_amenities input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
  $scope.ot_Filter = function (location) {
   var shouldBeShown = false;
   for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (location.amenities.indexOf(x[i]) !== -1) {
          shouldBeShown = true;
            break;
        }
    }
   return shouldBeShown;
  };
}



    $scope.$watch('nas',
    function (newValue, oldValue) {
        for (jdx in $scope.markers) {
            $scope.markers[jdx].setMap(null);
        }
        $scope.markers = [];
        for (idx in $scope.nas) {
            createMarker($scope.nas[idx]);
        }
    }, true);
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 220px;
  width: 400px;
}

.infoWindowContent {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
#total_items
{
 margin:0px auto;
 padding:0px;
 text-align:center;
 color:#0B173B;
 margin-top:50px;
 border:2px dashed #013ADF;
 font-size:20px;
 width:200px;
 height:50px;
 line-height:50px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
#amount
{
 color:#DF7401;
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
#slider-range
{
 margin:0px auto;
 padding:0px;
 text-align:center;
 width:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&extension=.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="hotelApp" ng-controller="ContentControler">
<div id="map"></div>
    <div id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers"></div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in nas = (names | filter:{prop_Name:location_name} | filter:pmaxFilter | filter:ot_Filter)">{{ x.prop_Name }}</li>
    </ul>
    
    
<div class="hosting_amenities">
<h3>Filter:</h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="1">WIFI
 <input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="2">TV
<input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="3">Cable TV
<input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="4">Klima 
<button ng-click="am_en();">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current script, when you select 2 elements, like TV and WiFi, you are showing the rooms that have TV **or** WiFi. You should change your code in order to select only the rooms that have TV **and** WiFi, so your inner function `$scope.ot_Filter` will be as follows:

```
$scope.ot_Filter = function (location) {
    var shouldBeShown = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (location.amenities.indexOf(x[i]) === -1) {
            shouldBeShown = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return shouldBeShown;
};
```

I've modified your script, adding WiFi to a location, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zcgs7yf6/20/)

Comment: There was a final problem when the program finished. How to avoid filtering when page loads first time. For example : Opening page with tv checked ?

Comment: question link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952927/angularjs-filter-page-loads-first-time

Answer (score 0):

You only check if something is checked and then set `shouldBeShown` to true and break. So you check for "OR" and not for "AND" with your checkboxes.

See your `$scope.am_en = function()`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (location.amenities.indexOf(x[i]) !== -1) {
                shouldBeShown = true;
                break;
            }
}
return shouldBeShown;
```

You need to modify your if-statement to check ALL checked checkboxes/filters. Maybe you can think about using binary information for amenities.

Example:

- 00 = no amenity
- 01 = only WiFi
- 10 = only TV
- 11 = TV and WiFi

Then you can store:

- 0 for nothing
- 1 for only WiFi
- 2 for only TV
- 3 for TV and Wifi
- ...

This would make a check easier as you can use the modulo operator.